# Access new web site via browser with IP address?

Tags: apache, hosting, ip, cpanel, whm

Ive set up a new site with WHM but havent got the DNS set up yet. I want to be able to access the site via a browser so I can set up a CMS. Usually, I can just do this by entering the IP address into the browser, but this time I just get a page saying that Apache is working on the server.

Does anyone know a way round this?
Thanks!

[image: Apache]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the request your browser is sending doesn't include the correct `Host:` in the HTTP header, so the web server replies with the a default catch-all page.

You can either

- setup a private (local) authoritative DNS server with a **yoursite.com** zone, and set your system's DNS to point to this DNS server, or
- temporarily trick the DNS resolution in your local system by registering **whatever.yoursite.com** with it's corresponding IP address in `/etc/hosts` file (in unix-like systems). There's an equivalent file in MS Windows systems, look for a file named `hosts` in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc`.

I'd try with the latter first, as it's just a matter of adding a single line to a text file:

```
203.0.113.22    whatever.yoursite.com
```

You may need to restart your browser.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered you can also do it by clicking the IP address when you list the account in WHM. It brings up 192.169.4.1/~yoursitename in the browser